# jQuery HTML validtion not working for manipulated DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on validations of input fields. The validations work fine the first time input is added through in the input fields. Because multiple fields can be added (see it as adding another row to the table) I manipulate the input fields when clicking on add (the row is cloned and then added to the bottom of the table).

When adding a second row the HTML validations do not work anymore and always give true when doing `elem.checkValidity()` on the element. I don't see any errors in the console and the validation attributes don't changes during the DOM manipulation. I've also check if there is difference between browsers but both Chrome and Firefox act the same.

I'm guessing that somehow I have to rebind the validity to the element after the manipulation but I'm not sure.

Here's the code:

**HTML input fields**

```
 <input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.0001" id="trapezoid_x" class="form-control input_trapezoid trapezoid_x" placeholder="Position x">
 <input type="number" min="0" max="1" step="0.0001" id="trapezoid_p" class="form-control input_trapezoid trapezoid_p" placeholder="Probability">
```

**jQuery custom function to check validity and add input error**

```
function validInputFields(elem, result) {      
  if (!elem.checkValidity()) { 
    result[$(elem).attr("id")] = elem.validationMessage;
    addInputError($(elem), elem.validationMessage)valid
  } else {
    removeInputError($(elem));
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Code when the trapezoid is added and DOM is manipulated**

```
function handleClickAddTrapezoidBtn() {
  const removeIcon = $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-trash");
  const removeTrapezoidBtn = $("<button>").attr({"type": "button"})
                                          .addClass("btn btn-outline-danger trapezoid_remove_btn")
                                          .append(removeIcon);
  const saveIcon = $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-check");
  const saveTrapezoidBtn = $("<button>").attr({"type": "button"}) 
                                        .addClass("btn btn-outline-success trapezoid_save_btn")
                                         .append(saveIcon);
  const clonedTrapezoidFormGroup = $(".trapezoid_form_group").last().clone();
  const valX = parseFloat($(".trapezoid_x").last().val());
  const valP = parseFloat($(".trapezoid_p").last().val());
  const idx = $(".trapezoid_form_group").length -= 1;
  let trapezoids = currentTrapezoids().length > 0 ? currentTrapezoids() : [];
  const inputFields = [$("#trapezoid_x")[0], $("#trapezoid_p")[0]];
  let invalidInput = {};

  $(inputFields).each(function(i, d) {
    validInputFields(d, invalidInput);
  });

  if (!$.isEmptyObject(invalidInput)) { return }
  if (!checkPositionXValue($(".trapezoid_x:last"))) { return }

  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).attr("data-idx", idx).addClass("added_trapezoid");
  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).find(".trapezoid_x").val(valX);
  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).find(".trapezoid_p").val(valP);
  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).find("#add_trapezoid").remove();
  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).find(".input-group-append").append(saveTrapezoidBtn);
  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).find(".input-group-append").append(removeTrapezoidBtn);
  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).find(".invalid-feedback").remove();
  $(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup).find(".trapezoid_x").removeClass("input-warning");
  $(".trapezoid_form_group").last().before(clonedTrapezoidFormGroup);
  $(".trapezoid_x").last().val("");
  $(".trapezoid_p").last().val("");
  $(".trapezoid_form_group").find(".invalid-feedback")
                            .removeClass("input-warning")
                            .empty();
  $(".trapezoid_form-group").find(".trapezoid_x").removeClass("input-warning");

  let data = [];
  data.push(valX);
  data.push(valP);
  trapezoids.push(data);
  sortTrapezoids(trapezoids);
  currentTrapezoids(trapezoids);

  $(".trapezoid_x").last().focus();

  $(removeTrapezoidBtn).bind("click", handleClickRemoveTrapezoidBtn);
  $(saveTrapezoidBtn).bind("click", handleClickSaveTrapezoidBtn);
}
```

Comment: Validation is initialized when the DOM is created so you may have to set your validation settings for the form outside of document ready function

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dickrichie. I've figured out what went wrong. Because I'm cloning it also cloned the ID of the input elements. When checking the input fields it takes the ID of the element. If you have multiple fields with the same ID it will take the first it finds on the page. I'm removing the ID's from cloned input fields and now it validates.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what caused the issue. I'm cloning the input fields to later add them to the table. When doing so I also cloned the ID of the input fields and adding them to the page. When checking the validation of the input fields it would take the ID of the input fields.

If there are more then 1 of the same ID present on the page it will take the first one. In my case it was the cloned input field.

I found out by checking which field is being checked through a console.log.

I'm removing the ID from the cloned element and now it work as expected.